# Can I use etherscan with my local development blockchain?

Tags: dev-chain

I would like to run my local private blockchain for development purpose, but without a good visualization tool, it is tedious to use.

I know Etherscan.io which is a great blockchain visualization tool. Can I connect Etherscan to a local blockchain? If not, would downloading the whole website and changing the address of the node to connect to make it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etherscan isn't open source, and you can't simply download the website and change the node. Most information is likely rendered on a server, rather than on the client.

You may be interested in something like Ganache, which has a nice UI for debugging:
https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache

Comment: Thanks (+1). Ganache has indeed a nice UI but most features only work with truffle :(

Answer (score 8):

There's a tool for this called [Ethernal](https://tryethernal.com/). If you're a Hardhat user, there's an [Ethernal plugin](https://github.com/tryethernal/hardhat-ethernal) for it. If you're a Truffle user, you have to use the [CLI](https://github.com/tryethernal/ethernal-cli) directly.

Comment: this is answer we were all looking for!